# How can I send notifications when a user is logged out?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I have developed push notifications (FCM) functionality in my application, working fine. Only issue I am facing is when device is offline/logout within this time if user getting notifications they are missing, not delivering when user come online.

[image]

Comment: Give more detail, it is impossible to help you without any sample code.

Comment: why not use fcm Firebase Cloud Messaging it is more optimized than GCM. and it's easy to implement

Comment: @MasterFathi  ohhh ..sorry..i edited my question..  i've already used FCM

Comment: @PedroMassango i added image to explain the error

Comment: is the notification object that you sent contains only data or it contains notification body?

Comment: @MasterFathi  contains body and data ..... i think my error occurs because i delete token_id when user clicks on logout

Comment: i updated my answer check it out

Answer (score 0):

The push notification have a expiration time, this is a paremeter when you send the notification, this expiration is of the magnitude of days, when the user come back online within the period the notifacation is delivered. Maybe you need create the notification with Firebase, because the GCM soon they will be deprecated.

The registration token may change when:

```
The app deletes Instance ID
The app is restored on a new device
The user uninstalls/reinstall the app
The user clears app data.
```

Answer (score 0):

from what i see from your screenshot the problem occurs because you are sending a notification to an empty deviceToken. you need to stop deleting that token if you want the notification to be sent.

To get a new token just from your android app write this

```
System.out.print("Firebase Token "+ FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());
```

Comment: i did that , but when logout  and login with another user to my app....token_id doesn't  change ....i mean 2 users with one token id so i try to delete token id when logout

Comment: The Token is an ID result of the relation App-Device

Comment: @esdebon so.. can i use an Auth ID token replacement for FCM Token/Instance ID token to push notifications.............. i think an Auth ID token identifies a specific user of a specific application ??

Comment: you need to store the token for each user not delete it and when u want to send notification to that user or all the users connected u go to the user list and get all the tokens and send each one of them separately.